# How can a guest user change the language in liferay 6.2+?

Tags: internationalization, liferay-6

My intention is a guest can change the language of the portal but I am not getting how to do this.

Your help is really beneficial for me.

Thanks

asif aftab

Comment: he can change it by adding /de/ or /en/ to the url.
hope i understood the question...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matthisas G. My question is how a guest can change the language of portlet. If you login then by myaccount->display setting-> change language. This is the procedure by which a register user can change the language of liferay 6.2. But my intention is how to change the language of portal by guest user means the not register user. To change the language I used language portlet having public page property but a guest can't change the language.

Comment: If you know further query then please ask and share valuable information.

Comment: Anyone visiting site without login considered as guest and there is no way to differntiate them, so there is no meaning giving them language change option as it applies to all guest users

Comment: We are developing a simple hospital website, in which if you are user then can avail all the features and facility provided by the hospital. But this is a big project and we have to develop it in 18 different languages. So if a guest user want to register then may be possibility he or she is not known to English language so wants to change language. So a guest user can change the language and it is simple concept I think lots of site providing such a facility because every user is not registered user. I think my intention is know now clear for you. Still you have any doubt you can ask.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Still waiting for answer

Answer (score 1):

Add simple the Language-Portlet to Start-Page of your Portal. By this portlet the guest can simple switch current user language.

[image]

Or you make it like www.liferay.com - put the language id to url:

```
https://your-liferay-domain/de/web/portal
https://your-liferay-domain/en/web/portal
https://your-liferay-domain/it/web/portal
...
```

Comment: I already added this portlet to my portal but a guest user can access this but language will not change. I searched this issue so someone commented that this is a bug in liferay.

Comment: This answer is correct. If you know there is a bug, 1) there is no answer here, 2) At least you should give us a specific Liferay version. e.g I can't reproduce that bug in liferay 6.1.0

Comment: Thanks Yannicular. I am currently using Liferay 6.2 CE and my database is sql server. I am using apache tomcat server 7. If you have any other information then please share with me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the OP already mentioned in the comments, this is a [confirmed Liferay 6.2 bug](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-42075)

The same question is answered in [Liferay forums](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/32627016)

So, the way I see this, you have these options

1. Downgrade to a Liferay 6.1+ or older version
2. Create a patch, either by adding an ext-hook or recompiling the code
3. If you have Enterprise Edition, ask for a hot-fix

If it wasn't for the bug, things should work as @Mark says, this is the supposed behavior.

Comment: Yes I also realized that I have to use hook if possible else no option then ext. If you have any reference link which will useful for me then please share. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You'll have to read the source and find the buggy code, before writing any patch/hook. Have you done that?

Comment: about writing a hook, there are plenty of tutorials out there, and that's definitely out of this thread's scope. The same goes for solving a bug in a project with 200 mb source. Patching this bug is a long shot, so please make new questions for your sub-tasks.

Comment: btw I noticed that you don't accept any answers on your questions. not even your own answers. You are not helping this forum by keeping questions unanswered. please read the guideline again http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: Sorry yannicular, but I didn't implement hook, I know theoretically but not practically and the problem with me is in my company I am alone working in this project(Health website) so I am facing lots of pressure and I want to implement things as fast as possible. This is one of the reason that I am asking more and more question and looking for straight answer. Thanks for your comments and I appreciate your reply its really helpful for me. Please comments on my post I really feel good if someone comments on my post. Thanks and sorry for silly question.

Comment: I don't think you understood what i said. I insist you read the link I gave you before, and accept the answers that worked for you. Now about your problem, you ll have to decide on making a decision (downgrade or hook). If you decide to make a hook, you might have some luck requesting one from the liferay forum. If this doesn't work out, you'll have to create one yourself

Answer (score -3):

You can use Google Translator for this purpose.

Comment: There is a concept called internationalization by which a user can change its language. Suppose a user is not so aware to such browser or very new to the internet so he/she is not able to change language, and hence it is our responsibility to provide them such a privilege to easily get the things that they want.

Comment: Yes, Google provides a JS for this purpose. Simply by including that JS into your code you could provide the guest user an option to change the language of the portal.

Comment: Thanks Atin. Sorry to say but if you provide that .js file and if you have some snippet code then its really very helpful for me.